# React Native setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on a React Native app that has a screen with a custom swiper component that allows users to swipe through a collection of photos. Initially I make an API call that loads 10 photos, and users can swipe to load another 10 when the current photo index nears the end of the array that they are stored in.

Since I'm doing pagination, I would like to keep track of what page the user is on. For example, if the index is between 0-9, then the user is on the first page, 10-19 for the second page, etc.

I've been able to successfully track the page that the user is on, but I'm generating a warning when updating it within the state, which makes me think there is a better way to handle this.

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition
(such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render
methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side
effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

Here is my implementation of the screen:

```
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
import styles from './styles/ImageScreenStyle'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

class ImageScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: this.props.navigation.state.params.page,
      key: this.props.navigation.state.params.key,
      items: this.props.navigation.state.params.array,
    }
    this._fetchNextPage = this._fetchNextPage.bind(this)
    this._renderNewItems = this._renderNewItems.bind(this)
    this._renderNewPage = this._renderNewPage.bind(this)
  }

  // Update the parent state to push in new items
  _renderNewItems(index, items) {
    let oldItems = this.state.items
    let newItems = oldItems.concat(items)
    this.setState({ items: newItems, key: index })
  }

  // This generates a warning but still works?
  _renderNewPage(page) {
    let newPage = this.state.page
    newPage.current = page
    this.setState({ page: newPage })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        showsButtons
        loop = { false }
        index = { this.state.key }
        renderPagination = { this._renderPagination }
        renderNewItems = { this._renderNewItems }
        renderNewPage = { this._renderNewPage }
        fetchNextPage = { this._fetchNextPage }
        page = { this.state.page }>
        { this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <View key = { key } style = { styles.slide }>
              <Image
                style = {{ width, height }}
                resizeMode = 'contain'
                source = {{ uri: item.photo.images[1].url }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </Swiper>
    )
  }

  _renderPagination(index, total, context) {
    const photoPage = Math.floor(index / 10) + 1
    const currentPage = this.page.current

    // Update the current page user is on
    if (photoPage !== currentPage) {
      return this.renderNewPage(photoPage)
    }

    // Add more photos when index is greater or equal than second last item
    if (index >= (total - 3)) {
      this.fetchNextPage().then((data) => {
        // Here is where we will update the state
        const photos = data.photos

        let items = Array.apply(null, Array(photos.length)).map((v, i) => {
          return { id: i, photo: photos[i] }
        })

        // Pass in the index because we want to retain our location
        return this.renderNewItems(index, items)
      })
    }
  }

  _fetchNextPage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const currentPage = this.state.page.current
      const nextPage = currentPage + 1
      const totalPages = this.state.page.total

      if (nextPage < totalPages) {
        const PAGE_URL = '&page=' + nextPage

        fetch(COLLECTION_URL + PAGE_URL + CONSUMER_KEY)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          return resolve(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return reject(error)
        })
      }
    })
  }
}

export default ImageScreen
```

The pagination is handled within one function, and I'm using the _renderNewItems and _renderNewPage methods to handle the states for the new photos and page index.

**Update**

I've changed my code up to reflect answers provided, but am not having any luck getting the warning to suppress. I figured the bindings and changing to the `componentWillMount()` method would help. Here is where I currently stand:

```
class ImageScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: '',
      key: '',
      items: []
    }
    this._fetchNextPage = this._fetchNextPage.bind(this)
    this._renderNewItems = this._renderNewItems.bind(this)
    this._renderNewPage = this._renderNewPage.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      page: this.props.navigation.state.params.page,
      key: this.props.navigation.state.params.key,
      items: this.props.navigation.state.params.array
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        showsButtons
        loop = { false }
        index = { this.state.key }
        renderPagination = { this._renderPagination.bind(this) }
        renderNewItems = { this._renderNewItems.bind(this) }
        renderNewPage = { this._renderNewPage.bind(this) }
        fetchNextPage = { this._fetchNextPage.bind(this) }>
        { this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <View key = { key } style = { styles.slide }>
              <Image
                style = {{ width, height }}
                resizeMode = 'contain'
                source = {{ uri: item.photo.images[1].url }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </Swiper>
    )
  }

  _renderPagination(index, total, context) {
    const photoPage = Math.floor(index / 10) + 1
    const statePage = this.state.page.current

    if (photoPage !== statePage) {
      return this._renderNewPage(photoPage)
    }


    if (index >= (total - 3)) {
      this._fetchNextPage().then((data) => {
        const photos = data.photos

        let items = Array.apply(null, Array(photos.length)).map((v, i) => {
          return { id: i, photo: photos[i] }
        })

        return this._renderNewItems(index, items)
      })
    }
  }

  _renderNewItems(index, items) {
    let oldItems = this.state.items
    let newItems = oldItems.concat(items)
    this.setState({ items: newItems, key: index })
  }

  // TO-DO: Fix the warning this generates
  _renderNewPage(page) {
    let newPage = this.state.page
    newPage.current = page
    this.setState({ page: newPage })
  }

  _fetchNextPage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const currentPage = this.state.page.current
      const nextPage = currentPage + 1
      const totalPages = this.state.page.total

      if (nextPage < totalPages) {
        const PAGE_URL = '&page=' + nextPage

        fetch(COLLECTION_URL + PAGE_URL + CONSUMER_KEY)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          return resolve(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return reject(error)
        })
      }
    })
  }
}

export default ImageScreen
```

**Update 2**

Fixed the problem. As Felix pointed out in the comments, the `renderPagination` method was re-rendering frequently, so I used the `onMomentumScrollEnd` prop of the Swiper (from react-native-swiper) to update the page information. For anyone who might need it, here is my code:

```
class ImageScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: '',
      key: '',
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      page: this.props.navigation.state.params.page,
      key: this.props.navigation.state.params.key,
      items: this.props.navigation.state.params.array
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        showsButtons
        loop = { false }
        index = { this.state.key }
        onMomentumScrollEnd = { this._onMomentumScrollEnd.bind(this) }
        renderPagination = { this._renderPagination.bind(this) }
        renderNewItems = { this._renderNewItems.bind(this) }
        fetchNextPage = { this._fetchNextPage.bind(this) }>
        { this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <View key = { key } style = { styles.slide }>
              <Image
                style = {{ width, height }}
                resizeMode = 'contain'
                source = {{ uri: item.photo.images[1].url }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </Swiper>
    )
  }

  _renderNewItems(index, items) {
    let oldItems = this.state.items
    let newItems = oldItems.concat(items)
    this.setState({ items: newItems, key: index })
  }

  _renderPagination(index, total, context) {
    if (index >= (total - 3)) {
      this._fetchNextPage().then((data) => {
        const photos = data.photos

        let items = Array.apply(null, Array(photos.length)).map((v, i) => {
          return { id: i, photo: photos[i] }
        })

        return this._renderNewItems(index, items)
      })
    }
  }

  _fetchNextPage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const currentPage = this.state.page.current
      const nextPage = currentPage + 1
      const totalPages = this.state.page.total

      if (nextPage < totalPages) {
        const PAGE_URL = '&page=' + nextPage

        fetch(COLLECTION_URL + PAGE_URL + CONSUMER_KEY)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          return resolve(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return reject(error)
        })
      }
    })
  }

  _onMomentumScrollEnd(e, state, context) {
    const photoPage = Math.floor(state.index / 10) + 1
    const statePage = this.state.page.current
    console.log('Current page: ' + photoPage)
    console.log('State page: ' + statePage)


    if (photoPage !== statePage) {
      this._renderNewPage(photoPage)
    }
  }

  _renderNewPage(page) {
    let newPage = this.state.page
    newPage.current = page
    this.setState({ page: newPage })
  }
}

export default ImageScreen
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me: One of the helper functions that call `this.setState` must be called when `render()` is called. That is not good. Don't call `this.setState` in functions that are called on render.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm stumped as to where this might be happening - do you mind taking another look at my updated code?

Comment: You need to look at the implementation of `Swiper`. If any of the functions you pass to it (`renderNewItems`, `renderNewPage`, `renderPagination`) is called inside of `Swiper`'s `render` method, then you cannot call `setState` in those methods. The very fact the the prop names start with `render` seems to indicate that you should not call `setState` in the corresponding methods. If all you want is to know which page is rendered, I'm sure `Swiper` provides a way to pass a callback to get notified of these changes.

Comment: [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper/blob/cabf42a313c462e885eee6e2368d10a8408893ac/src/index.js#L634), `Swiper` calls `this.props.renderPagination` in its `render` method. The function you pass as `renderPagination` prop indirectly calls `setState`, which is why you get that error. [According to the issues on the repo](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper/issues/133), you can use `onMomentumScrollEnd` to be notified of page changes.

Comment: @FelixKling That was the fix! I moved everything to a `_onMomentumScrollEnd` method and the state was no longer being called from `renderPagination`. Thanks for looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

> use should update

```
shouldComponentUpdate();
```

if above will not work then you can also try this.

```
this.forceUpdate();
```

Comment: Which method are you suggesting I call this in?

Comment: for updating state you can use these method. some time we faced these error then we need to update the state forcefully(if its necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think issue is in this line:

`renderPagination = { this._renderPagination }`

you forgot to `bind` this event, and this is creating the `loop` because you are using `this.setState`, inside this. Try this:

```
renderPagination = { this._renderPagination.bind(this) }
```

**Reason**: Whenever you use `this.setState`, `React` `render` the whole `component` again, and if you didn't `bind` any method then, that will get called during each `rendering`, it will not create any problem until you are not using `setState` in that function, but if you use `setState` in that then it will create the `loop`, it will again call `render` again `setState` .......

Comment: he defined the `binding` for all other methods, but he forgot to `bind` this one: `_renderPagination`, please check.

Comment: You are right. That doesn't explain the error in the question though. I fail to see how not binding the function "is creating the `loop`". If the function is not bound, `this` will be `undefined` and a completely different error will be thrown.

Comment: please check the console of this `jsfiddle`, this is what i was trying to say: https://jsfiddle.net/o3czw0L2/

Comment: But that doesn't apply here. The OP uses `renderPagination = { this._renderPagination }` not `renderPagination = { this._renderPagination() }` (i.e. they are not calling `this._renderPagination` directly). While it is correct that `.bind()` is required, it doesn't solve the actual issue.

Comment: ohh got it, sorry my mistake, will delete the answer :)